# ratification path for web3 beta to production

Tags: web3js

What is are the prerequisites for bringing web3js 1.0 beta to production?

The disparity between the 0.x software and the 1.x software has gone on for 1/3rd of the web3 project's lifespan now, it isn't clear to me the path to production is.

Comment: I think you can gain some insight by looking at the backlog available on the GitHub Project: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/projects/1

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi "Updated on Jun 30, 2017" /facepalm